# Как удалить повторяющиеся слова из строки, Python

Tags: python-3.6

Из текста:
text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The dog is dissapointed'

Должно остаться:
text = 'quick brown fox jumps over lazy. is dissapointed'

Это мой вариант, но он не удаляет первое "the" и "dog" после точки:

`text_lower = text.lower().split()
print(" ".join(sorted(set(text_lower), key=text_lower.index)))`

Comment: Неудивительно. Этот код делает сет, а не удаляет элементы, которые встречаются более одно раза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На `Python` не пишу совсем (учил когда-то), но почему-то стало интересно попробовать решить задачу. `OrderedDict` использовал, потому что не уверен, что `dict` гарантирует тот порядок, в котором в него добавили значения.

В `count_words` в значения словаря добавляется ещё и третий элемент для сохранения оригинального регистра слова.

Входное значение: 
`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The dog is dissapointed`
Результат: 
`quick brown fox jumps over lazy. is dissapointed`

```py
from collections import OrderedDict


def count_words(words):
    """
    Посчитать количество каждой встречающейся строки из входного массива строк.
    :param words: Входной массив строк
    :return: Вернёт словарь вида 'lowercase_word_or_symbol': [index, count, original_word],
             например: <class 'dict'>: {'the': [0, 3, 'The'], 'quick': [1, 1, 'quick'] }
    """
    result = dict()
    index = 0
    for word in words:
        lower_case_word = word.lower()
        if lower_case_word in result:
            result[lower_case_word][1] += 1
        else:
            result[lower_case_word] = [index, 1, word]
        index += 1

    return result


def get_diff(ordered_words):
    """
    Получить только те слова, которые в оригинальном тексте встречались один раз.
    :param ordered_words:
    Ожидается словарь вида:
    <class 'dict'>: {'the': [0, 3, 'The'], 'quick': [1, 1, 'quick'] }
    :return:
    """
    result_ordered = OrderedDict()
    for key, value in ordered_words.items():
        new_key = (ordered_words[key][0], key)
        if new_key not in result_ordered and ordered_words[key][1] == 1:
            result_ordered[ordered_words[key][0]] = value[2]

    return result_ordered


def get_sentence(ordered_words, symbols):
    """
    Соединить значения словаря через пробел, не ставя перед первым слово пробел и
    перед знаками препинания.
    :param ordered_words:
    Ожидается словарь вида:
    OrderedDict([(1, 'quick'), (2, 'brown'), (3, 'fox')])
    :param symbols: знаки препинания
    :return:
    """
    result = ""
    prefix = ""
    for key, value in ordered_words.items():
        if value in symbols:
            result += value
        else:
            result += prefix + value
            prefix = " "
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    symbols = {'.'}  # или {'.', ',', '?', '!'}
    text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The dog is dissapointed"
    intermediate_list = [' ' + c + ' ' if c in symbols else c for c in text]
    counted_words = count_words(''.join(intermediate_list).split())
    ordered_words = get_diff(counted_words)
    sentence = get_sentence(ordered_words, symbols)
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: Я отдаленно понимаю, что в коде, но блин, мне еще многому учиться